# Unable to connect to sql server with odbc on QT ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, odbc, qtsql

I'm trying to connect to locahost sql server but all the time I receive error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Loggin faield for user 'user'. QODBC3: Unable to connect;
```

I'm using Qt 5.4 on ubuntu.

Connection string:

```
QString connectionString = QString(("DRIVER=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=FightClubDB;UID=kudryavii;PWD=Pass;"));
QSqlDatabase db{QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", connectionId)};
db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);

return connectionId;
```

Comment: Forgot `plugins\sqldrivers` contents to be put near executable? Or, maybe, SSL libraries are missing -- try also installing the OpenSSL via Qt Installer.

Comment: @MasterAler I'm using ubuntu,  I don't have ubuntu installer. I just used apt-get install qt via command "sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev". And why I should to palce sqldrivers in the same directory as executable if I specify full directory to the driver?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed mssql-server via this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15
then to connect to sql server you will have to use "SA" username not you account name...